# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'PyQt5.QtWebEngineView'

Tags: python, python-3.x, package, pyqt5, python-webbrowser

I am executing the code on `windows` system and over `Pycharm`.
I have got an error :

> ***C:\Users\HP\PycharmProjects\untitled2\venv\Scripts\python.exe C:/Users/HP/PycharmProjects/untitled2/MyBrowser.py
>   Traceback (most recent call last):
>     File "C:/Users/HP/PycharmProjects/untitled2/MyBrowser.py", line 5, in 
>       from PyQt5.QtWebEngineView import *
>   ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'PyQt5.QtWebEngineView'***

How to fix this issue? My code:

```
    from PyQt5.QtCore import *
    from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
    from PyQt5.QtGui import *
    from PyQt5.QtWebEngineWidgets import *
    from PyQt5.QtWebEngineView import *

    import sys

    class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
        def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
            super(MainWindow, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

            self.setWindowTitle(" Shikhar ")
            self.browser = QWebView()
            self.browser.setUrl( QUrl("http://www.google.com") )
            self.setCentralWidget(self.browser)

    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = MainWindow()
    window.show()
    app.exec()
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using an out of date version of PyQt. Update to v5.5 or higher.